# Does javascript use optimization in boolean expressions?

Tags: javascript

I have strange error when I decided to build ordinary web-form validation with classic javascript. There are several "onblur" handlers for input text fields and one "form-submit" handler.

When I use them like that:

```
function loginCheck() {
  ... return true of false 
}

function passwordCheck() { 
   ...
}

function formValidation() {
  return loginCheck() && passwordCheck();
}
```

It doesn't work as I expect: "passwordCheck" never called if loginCheck is failed!

Finally I have workaround

```
function formValidation() {
  ok = loginCheck();
  ok &= passwordCheck();
  return ok;
}
```

Now password check is executed. But when I choose:

```
function formValidation() {
      ok = loginCheck();
      ok = ok && passwordCheck();
      return ok;
    }
```

passwordCheck is never called again if loginCheck failed.

Moreover: loginCheck & passwordCheck return boolean values, but &= operator covert it to "0" or "1". "0" doesn't work for my `onsubmit="return checkForm"` handler.   I have to convert my &= result to boolean once again:

```
function formValidation() {
      ok = loginCheck();
      ok &= passwordCheck();
      return ok != 0;
    }
```

It is a normal behavior for javascript engines ?

Comment: `&` is bitwise AND and will always return a number. `&&` is logial AND and will return the value of the expression which determines the overall outcome. A shortcut to convert any value into its boolean equivalent is to use double negation `!!`.

Comment: Can somehow change the horrible title? I can't think of something that's clear and still attractive.

Comment: Some refactoring is in order if you need to do a password check after a login check fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. It's called a [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and is both handy and very common (i.e. is present in a lot of languages (C, C++, Java, Perl, many others), not just JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

That is the way it should be!

Quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) : the  logical conjunction (a.k.a. `&&`) "results in true if **both** of its operands are true, otherwise the value of false."
In other words, if the first operand is false, there is no need to proceed with the evaluation of the second one because the result will always be false.

So an expression like

```
if(condition1 && condition2)
```

is equivalent to

```
if(condition1){
    if(condition2){

    }
}
```

So you see that if the first condition is false, there is no need to continue evaluating your expression, because the answer will be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly run both functions, you can choose to only run `&&` when both have been evaluated:

```
var l = loginCheck(),    // will evaluate
    p = passwordCheck(); // will evaluate

return l && p;           // if l failed, p will be ignored, but both functions
                         // have been evaluated anyway
```

Comment: `return loginCheck() | passwordCheck();` does the same thing in one line, but in this instance why you would want to do the password check if the login failed is a mystery.

Comment: @EJP: True, but then again that returns a number. I was just posting this as an alternative to the sophisticated `&=` way.

Comment: @EJP because my checks reoder UI. I'd like to show current errors to user

Comment: @pimvdb The OP'2 two methods both return boolean so this line returns a boolean too. It returns a number if the methods return a number.

Comment: @EJP: Well not exactly. `(true | false) === 1`.