# How to NOT return the last object in a boolean chain

Tags: javascript

I have code like this:

```
function doAThing(var1) {
    return typeof var1 === "object" && Object.keys(var1).length > 11;
}
```

I'm having a problem where when `var1` is NOT an object the function tries to return the value of the last statement: `Object.keys(var1).length > 11)`

Obviously, if `obj1` is not an object i don't want to try and get it's keys or it will blow up with `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`.

How can i get this function to return a boolean and NOT try to check `var1`'s keys if it's not an object?

Comment: Actually, the last condition shouldn't be evaluated as it shortcuts on the first `false` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858787/does-javascript-use-optimization-in-boolean-expressions

Can you post the complete code causing your issue and tell us what 'blow up' actually means (what error do you encounter)?

Comment: not sure you can shortcut as Object.keys will be evaluated anyway.

Comment: @cpugourou I wouldn't think so if it's following the truthy/falsy logic which it should be. Are you sure it would evaluate?

Comment: Updated.   If you cannot shortcut what would you suggest as an alternate?

Comment: Note that your `typeof` will not return the desired results in some cases. For instance, if `var1` is an array, `typeof var1` will still be `object`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a `null` check to your condition, as `typeof null` is also `object`:

```
function doAThing() {
    return !bool1
        && var1 !== null
        && typeof var1 === "object"
        && Object.keys(var1).length > 11);
}
```